Entity Framework dbContext multithreading question
I've read when using the Entity Framework dbContext, it's not thread-safe and you "shouldn't have multiple threads working on the same dbContext."
Will this code below break that rule? I'm passing the dbContext to an async method that suspends evaluation until RetrieveMatch completes. So I don't think that multiple threads will be working on it at the same time. I guess the general question is, is it not safe to pass dbContext to async methods if you always just await them one at at time.
        public static async Task TestingAsync ()
        {
            //Create the dbContext before calling the async method
            LostWorldsContext dbContext = new();

            //Get Match with Id 4 and pass in the dbContext
            Match m = await RetrieveMatch(4, dbContext);

            //Change something
            m.MaxPlayers = 4;
                
            //Save the changes
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public static async Task<Match> RetrieveMatch(int matchID, LostWorldsContext dbContext)
        {
            var match = await dbContext.Matches
                .Where(m => m.Id == matchID)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            return match;
        } 


On a side note, always dispose your DbContext: using LostWorldsContext dbContext = new(); Also, avoid the "OrDefault" flavours unless it is a valid scenario, and you are handling the fact that #null can come back. If you expect 1 result, use Single, It will throw a more meaningful if 0 or >1 result is found than a NullReferenceException later in the code.


I've read when using the Entity Framework DbContext, it's not thread-safe and you "shouldn't have multiple threads working on the same DbContext"

Correct.

Will this code below break that rule?

No. The code is fine because the await operators are strategically placed at the same call-sites that represent an initiation of asynchronous activity.

I guess the general question is, _"is it not safe to pass DbContext to async methods if you always just await them one at at time?

Generally and loosely speaking, yes.
...but as-ever, details matter, and there are plenty of exceptions.

Basically if all your async methods are awaited, you’ll be fine.
